# How can I match values based on criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, sorting, vlookup

I have two tables with various columns in an Excel sheet. In these two tables I have two columns (one per table) in which I have some alphanumeric values.

For example,

```
table 1 col A:NAMES: AB34092, AB34091
table 2 col N:NAMES: AB34092, AB34095
```

Each table also has some other columns (different between them) with values and text. I want to match the values of these two columns and, based on that, to copy and paste the data (rows) of columns of table 2 to table 1, so as to make it bigger for the information I have based on the same names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make the NAMES column the leftmost of each table. I'm assuming your that each of your tables has 10 columns, "Table 1" starts in cell `Sheet!A1` and that row 1 contains the headings for the table, so that your first name is on cell `A2`.

I'm further assuming that your Table 2 is in Sheet2 with a similar placement to that of Table 1.

Type the following on the cell `K2`, which should be exactly to the right of your table (if it ended on column J):

`=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$J$100,2,0)` and copy that down until the end of the table.

This will pull the second (hence the `2`) column from the data located in `Sheet2!A1:J100` where the first column matches the value in `A2`. Hope that's clear enough!

Comment: that was an airstrike, thank you very much. One last question, can I do it for a x number of columns together or only one each time?

Comment: @por.bet only one at a time, i'm afraid

Comment: @por.bet I was on my phone so I couldn't write a better answer earlier. To make the process smoother, you can use `=MATCH` to find the location of a string in a range and infer the column number rather than harcoding `2, 3, 4...` and so forth. As long as you have equal column headers on both tables, and all header cells are unique, it's as simple as having `=MATCH(K$1,Sheet2!$A$1:$Z$1,0)` instead of `2` in my answer above

Comment: @por.bet - Note that `Vlookup()` works almost explicitly from left to right. If you can't organize the data to do that, you could do [`Index/Match`](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup/) instead.